# References to ~ in a script break when run under sudo

Tags: linux, bash, sh, python-venv

I am confused about sudo and why it is doing this

```
python3 -m venv ~/myvenv/env                       | works
sudo python3 -m venv ~/myvenv/env (command line)   | works
```

If I then put the command `python3 -m venv ~/myvenv/env` into a bash script `script.sh` then I get the following results like this..

```
sudo ./script.sh | fails
./script.sh      | works
```

I am rtying to run this command inside a bash script that needs to be launched with `sudo`, anyone tell me why ti is not working?

Comment: When it fails, what is the error?

Comment: I'm confused. The title says it fails when run with sudo. But the example that fails is the one without sudo.

Comment: When it fails there is no error output. Just doesn't create the venv

Comment: Got the fail and works the wrong way round, fixed the op now :)

Comment: Try replacing `~/myvenv/env` with the absolute pathname. When the script is run via `sudo`, `~` is root's home directory, not your directory.

Comment: Or use `~yourusername/myvenv/env`

Comment: BTW, you can use `SUDO_USER` to get the username of the user who invoked `sudo`, if you want to dynamically look up that user's home directory.

Answer (score 1):

When the script is run via `sudo`, the `~` in the pathname is interpreted by the root shell, so it's replaced with root's home directory, not your home directory.

You should either copy the `~/myvenv` folder to root's directory, or use a full pathname to point to this environment.

```
python3 -m venv ~myname/myvenv/env
```

Comment: A further note, when you run `sudo python3 -m venv ~/myvenv/env`, your shell expands `~` to your home directory **before** sudo is launched. With the script, expansion of `~` is delayed.